# Python: Total sum of a list of numbers with the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I have this problem:

I need to program a Python function that gives me back the sum of a list of numbers using a for loop.

I just know the following:

```
sum = 0
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
      sum = sum + x

print(sum)
```

Comment: I just edited the question. I hope this is more clear. Sorry for the ones that found the question unclear

Comment: It's still unclear. What does "if I wanted a different or any other list" mean? Are you saying you simply want to know how to prompt for user input or accept arguments? Please read this, and pay special attention to the "Golden Rule"[Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Other people only know what you *say*, they can't guess what you mean (or at least, they aren't likely to spend time writing an answer if they only have a guess about what you *might* be trying to say).

Comment: I edited the question again.

Comment: Okay, but what is the **question**? As in, something starting with a question word like "how" or "why", and ending with a question mark ("?")?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you mean is how to encapsulate that for general use, e.g. in a function:

```
def sum_list(l):
    sum = 0
    for x in l:
        sum += x
    return sum
```

Now you can apply this to any list. Examples:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum_list(l)

l = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ").split()))
sum_list(l)
```

But note that [`sum` is already built in!](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 6):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
sum = 0
for x in l:
    sum = sum + x
```

And you can change l for any list you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
sum=0
for s in range(0,len(x)):
   sum=sum+x[s]
print sum
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over indices when you can iterate directly over the list?

Comment: he asked basic operation of list. so some times i could use without last value.so i mentioned this way

Comment: The OP was already iterating over the list. `range(0, len(x))` (which could just be `range(len(x))`) *includes* the last item; and to exclude it, without messing with indices, you can do `for i in x[:-1]`.